# there is an error occuring exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input String: ""

Tags: java

i am   making a school project of online shopping and there is error occuring there is section of selecting the product u want to buy after i input y there is automatically "" inputeed by cmd at variable choice

```
 System.out.println(">Mobiles,Computers");
    System.out.println(">TV,Appliances,Electronics");
    System.out.println(">Men's Fashion");
    System.out.println(">Women's Fashion");
    System.out.println(">Home accessories");
    System.out.println("do you want to choose your product from above catagories or not \n enter y/n (REPLY IN SMALL LETTERS");
    c1=(char)br.read();
    while(c1 != 'n')
    {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice");
    System.out.println("Press 1: Mobiles,Laptops");
    System.out.println("Press 2: TV,Appliances,Electronics");
    System.out.println("Press 3: Men's Fashion");
    System.out.println("Press 4: Women's Fashion ");
    System.out.println("Press 5: Home accessories");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    int choice=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
    switch(choice)
    {
```

Comment: Try using the Scanner to read from the console:  `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
  
        String s = in.nextLine();`

Answer (score 1):

You can skip that line if it is empty:

```
String line = br.readLine();
if (line.isEmpty()) continue;
int choice = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
c1=(char)br.read();
```

That reads a **single** character from your input. I assume you did enter

> yENTER

on the keyboard. Thing is: you are only reading that one character, but not the newline/linebreak. Therefore that part "remains" in your input, and when you do the subsequent `readLine()` you get that *ENTER* part, boiling down to an empty string.

One solution: do all reads with `readLine()`, and then simply do

```
while(!stringFromUser.equalsIgnoreCase("n)) {
```

for example. Alternatively, you can simply do a "bogus" `readLine()` call *before* going `Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());`.

Finally: I assume you use a (Buffered)Reader on System.in. That doesn't make too much sense. You could instead use a `Scanner`. (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_scanner.htm) for some guidance)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Scanner to read from console:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
String s = in.nextLine();
```